# htaccess fake folder

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a site which you can create a network but I have a problem to create a fake folder.

Normal url;

```
mysite.com/profile.php?id=123&network=stackoverflow
```

What I want is

```
mysite.com/stackoverflow/profile.php?id=123
```

another example

Normal url;

```
mysite.com/home.php?network=stackoverflow
```

What I want is

```
mysite.com/stackoverflow/home.php
```

What is the htaccess code for this?
Thanks for your help

Comment: I am not familiar with mod_rewrite rules, but if you're using Apache, you will need to look into mod_rewrite.

Comment: err... "fake folder" isn't the correct term. it is called "URL rewrite" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)/(.*)$ /$2?network=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This will take

```
yoursite.com/anything_up_to_the_slash/anything.php?anything=anything
```

And rewrite it to

```
yoursite.com/anything.php?anything=anything&network=anything_up_to_the_slash
```

Comment: There will be security implications with this

Comment: What security implications do you think this will have?

Comment: `yoursite.com/private-folder/index.php?variable=testing-value`. At least with [Steven's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9660001/3536236) there is a finite list of possible allowed values `(home|profile)`. Prevents domain probing....

Answer (score 0):

In htaccess you'll need something like this rule:

```
 RewriteRule ^stackoverflow/(home|profile).php /$1.php?network=stackoverflow [QSA,L]
```

Note that the QSA modifier will make sure that any parameter passed into the url will be passed into the rewritten url.