# .htaccess trying to use directories as parameters

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have been contemplating the rewrite rules necessary for this, and am coming up to the realization that it might not be possible?  This post -> [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9659917/htaccess-fake-folder)

The only issue with that is it is backward from what I am looking for.  I am looking for this (If it's possible)

I have an actual directory that will run .. Let's call it `http://example.com/mydir/`

What I want is anything past that directory IE:

`http://example.com/mydir/this/that/the/other` <-- This URL is in address bar

Uses this file content IE:

`http://example.com/mydir/` This file content in browser since `this`, `that` and `other` directories don't technically exist.

However I still want `this`, `that` and `other` displayed in the address bar.  I don't want a redirect to just `mydir`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question fine then you can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(donations)/.+$ /$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: I attempted this, but when I do --> `/mydir/stuff` I get a `404` Error ... I simply want the page `mydir` displayed.

Comment: Negative .. Still 404

Comment: Did URL change in the browser?

Comment: No ..  Would you like to chat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47257/discussion-between-zak-and-anubhava)